# Django Deploy using Heroku - [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, heroku

I get this error ([Errno 2] No such file or directory) after I push the repo to heroku master. Here are my logs.

```
2012-04-17T18:24:53+00:00 app[web.1]: python: can't open file '/test/project/manage.py': [Errno 2]     No such file or directory

2012-04-17T18:24:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 2

2012-04-17T18:24:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2012-04-17T18:24:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created

2012-04-17T18:24:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting

2012-04-17T18:24:57+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command python /test/project/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:4473 --noreload 2012-04-17T18:24:57+00:00 app[web.1]: python: can't open file '/test/project/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

My Procfile looks like the following:

```
web: python /test/project/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT --noreload
```

I don't know why it can't open the file.  It opens fine when I am using my development server. Any ideas?  Thanks for reading.

Comment: Are you pushing the master branch of your local repo?

Comment: I think so. If I do git branch  the only thing I see is *master

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your current setup in your Procfile references an absolute path '/test/project/manage.py' that doesn't exist on Heroku. The '/test/ is the root of the instance you're running in and is incorrect. You should first change this to be the relative path, this is likely something like:

```
web: python project/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT --noreload
```

If this does not work you can explore the location of the project by running:

```
heroku run bash
```

This should place you in '/app' from here you can see what the path to start your project is.

Since your initial push likely failed to start the process you'll likely need to scale a web process. You can then do this with:

```
heroku scale web=1
```

Answer (score 1):

you can attach an `ls` to heroku to find out the actual structure of the file system.

```
> heroku run ls /
Running ls / attached to terminal... up, run.1
app  dev  home  lib64       mnt   sbin  usr
bin  etc  lib   lost+found  proc  tmp   var
```

It might be the case that they wrap your app inside an `app` directory

Comment: therefore.. you might want to do `web: python /app/test/project/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT --noreload` instead

Answer (score 0):

Try using [os.path](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to join the elements of the path., btw have you try it to change the ProcFile to read from worker? `python hellodjango/manage.py`

Edit later:

Try to run this three commands in order to make heroku master:

- `pip install -r ./requirements.txt`
- `foreman start`
- `heroku create mempy-demo --stac=cedar`
- git push heroku master

Now test a simple 'Hello World':

```
$ curl mempy-demo.herokuapp.com
```

Comment: I update my answer., it has to work now, by putting heroku master.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to change the environment variables (e.g add it in your wsgi.py file if that's where the error originates):

```
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "myblog.settings"                                                                
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myblog.settings")
```